# Linux CLI server with a virtual windows machine running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, virtualization

I have a ubuntu CLI server and I am wondering if it's possible to install a windows machine on a CLI server?

My hope is that I can take a pre-made VirutalBOX or VMware image and put it on my Ubuntu server and start it. After that login to it with a normal remote desktop.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Of course this is possible. Amazon and many others have been doing it for years. Why don't you go and do it? But do yourself a favor and steer clear of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For virtualbox ,

> VBoxHeadless -s

see http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2925/run-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-without-a-gui

and http://ayozone.org/2012/12/19/virtualbox-headless-install-and-manage-vm-without-gui/

If you are open to alternates, I suggest KVM . You can manage virtual machines with virt-manager or if you want a web interface, take a look at Proxmox

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox can be run headless, but I don't know if there are software dependencies that might affect installation of VirtualBox.

If VB can be installed on your cli system, you can also install the VB additions, which include a feature to allow connections to the BIOS using remote desktop protocol (rdp). That is free for home use and pay for in business uses. This feature will allow you to install Windows interactively and to repair Windows.

Answer (score -2):

After some small duckduckgoing (way more efficient than googling), found this article which seems to address your question:
http://www.howtoforge.com/vboxheadless-running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-4.1-on-a-headless-ubuntu-12.04-server

You might have to adapt a bit depending of your versions/setup

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It often helps to answer the question onsite instead of linking off site, or at least quote the bits that are important